# How can I get the response status from axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a react app like so:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Body = () => {
    const defaultVersions = [
        {
            version: '2.96.0',
            status: null,
        }
    ];

    const [versions, setVersions] = useState(defaultVersions);

    const getData = version => {
        axios.get(`https://cdn10/${version}/en-US/test.js`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.status);
                return response.status;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('in here');
            })
    };

    const onClick = () => {
        setVersions(versions.map(item => {
            const { version } = item;
            return { version, status: getData(version) };
        }));
    };

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={onClick}>Check Versions</button>
            <ul>
                {versions.map(item => {
                    const { version, status } = item;
                    return <li>{`${version}: ${status}`}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}

export default Body;
```

And the `console.log` in `getData` works, but when I try to use `getData` to set the new value in my state on the button click, it's returning `undefined`. I've tried making `getData` async/await, but that didn't work. Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `async/await` syntax and `Promise.all()` method.

For example:

```
const getData = async (version) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://cdn10/${version}/en-US/test.js`
    );
    return response.status;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return false;
  }
};

const onClick = async () => {
  const newVersions = await Promise.all(
    versions.map(async (item) => {
      const { version } = item;
      const status = await getData(version);
      return { version, status };
    })
  );
  setVersions(newVersions);
};
```

To see the whole example, please see [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-river-hq6pzq?file=/src/components/Body.js).

> PS: I forked your codesandbox and fixed errors.

Comment: Hm...it looks like with the above answer, it still comes back as `undefined`. And it looks like `version` also becomes `undefined` :(

Comment: Can you share your code in codesandbox?

Comment: Sure, let me try..

Comment: Here's a link to the sandbox (I had to change the api for privacy reasons, but I found a public GET api to use instead - it still results in the same `undefined` behavior as the above code): https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-turing-j9rydx?file=/src/components/Body.js

Comment: Umm, in your codesandbox, axios api throws an error, so I can't get the correct result. but I think this answer can help you. I updated my answer - @user18971245

Comment: @user18971245, did you test this code?

Comment: Thank you! The sandbox works, I think something else is making my api error out, will have to investigate that further but thanks for helping me get the response!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you found the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your getData is not returning anything, yes you are calling your function but you aren't returning the promise returned by your axios call. That's the first problem.
Second problem is that you are expecting multiple results when you click the button since you are doing a map of versions, in other words it's not just one promise, there could be many so you need to await all of them before setting the values

I think it's cleaner if we write it this way

```js
const getData = async (version) => {
try{
  const response = await axios.get(`https://cdn10/${version}/en-US/test.js`)
  return response.status;
} catch(e){
  console.log("Something went wrong")
  throw new Error(e)
}
       
};

const onClick = async () => {
 const myData = await Promise.all(
  versions.map(async (item) => {
      const { version } = item;
      const status = await getData(version)
      return { version, status };
    })
 )
 setVersions(myData)
}
```

This function can be improved but for sakes of this example this will work

Comment: Oh this answer is more complete ^^ I guess we all write around the same time xD

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you missed `return` in `getData`. In JavaScript the result of function that has no `return` is `undefined`. So it always returns `undefiend`.

When we return `axios.get` the return type is `Promise`. So we should use `async` `await` or `.then`. You can update your code like this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const defaultVersions = [
    {
        version: '2.96.0',
        status: null,
    }
];

const Body = () => {
    const [versions, setVersions] = useState(defaultVersions);

    const getData = version => axios.get(`https://cdn10/${version}/en-US/test.js`)
        .then(response => response.status)
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('in here');
        });

    const onClick = async () => {
        setVersions(
            await Promise.all(
                versions.map(async ({ version, status }) => ({
                    version,
                    status: (await getData(version)) ?? status,
                }))
            )
        );
    };

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={onClick}>Check Versions</button>
            <ul>
                {versions.map(item => {
                    const { version, status } = item;
                    return <li key={version}>{`${version}: ${status}`}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}

export default Body;
```

PS: When rendering list elements, we need to define a `key` prop.